# ELB with Multiple ENI Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am creating a load balancer in front of two Palo Alto's that are acting as Next Gen Firewalls for a web application behind them. These firewall devices have three ENI's:

- eth0: a management ENI placed in an internal management subnet
- eth1: a public ENI placed in an isolated, public subnet.
- eth2: a private ENI, placed in a DMZ subnet where the web application is also located.

When creating the ELB, I've selected the public subnet as the service location. After adding the instances to the ELB, and receiving an InService status, I navigate to the ELB address to find the management interface now exposed (eth0).

I can't seem to locate a way to manually specify the ENI for traffic on the ELB. Is this possible? If not, how am I to configure the ELB with eth1 only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-create-internal-load-balancer.html), it appears that the ELB will always route traffic to eth0:

> When you register an instance with an elastic network interface (ENI)
>   attached, the load balancer routes traffic to the primary IP address
>   of the primary interface (eth0) of the instance.

So I think your only solution is to swap eth0 and eth1 on your Palo Altos such that eth0 is the interface in your public subnet that you want ELB traffic routed to.